# QEMU startup zoom automation

Tags: qemu

Each time I start QEMU I do the same series of clicks: View->Zoom to fit, and then grab the corner of the QEMU window and drag to zoom about 2.5 times. Can this be automated so qemu just starts zoomed 2-3 times? Or at least in zoom to fit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qemu -display gtk,zoom-to-fit=on

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's where you find documentation for this: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/79b677d658d3d35e1e776826ac4abb28cdce69b8/qapi/ui.json#L1191

Comment: Is there a way to zoom it 2x as well?